# How do I add a Playsinline attribute to the Elementor video widget?

Tags: html, wordpress, attributes, elementor

I am trying to add a Playsinline HTML attribute to a video using the Elementor Page builder on Wordpress. I was able to accomplish this using pure HTML but I don't know how to format the key|value pair in Elementor custom attributes to make the video widget play in line on mobile.

Here is the code that I used to create the inline video.

```
<figure class="wp-block-video"><video controls src="https://staging1.ingoodhealth.co/wp-content/uploads/M1.mp4" Playsinline></video></figure>
```

Answer (score 0):

I add this to my videos and it works fine: playsinline="1"